# First Box.com integration. How do I query for a list of folders?

Tags: salesforce, integration

I have the oAuth stuff working as expected.  No challenges there.  I now need to use the access token to do something.  Nothing I have tried works.  I'm sure it's very simple, but I am not sure how to translate the examples in curl to http post/get requests.

Box.com help says:
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

How do i write that using http post/get?

As long as the requests are being sent via standard http functionality I don't believe my platform matters.  Regardless, I'm using Apex to write this in Salesforce.com.

Note: I know there is an app on the AppExchange to integrate Box.com and Salesforce.  For my purposes I don't want to rely on apps that are unique to a specific platform.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a GET request with headers and optionally XML / JSON as POST payload, not sure what's your specific problem? Have you actually tried writing some code?

Simple example: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm

Bit more advanced: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/scheduling-an-apex-call-from-the-command-line

CURL is a powerful tool and the list of [it's commandline options](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is not for the faint of heart. Still - use it as a reference, especially "-H" meaning HTTP header. I think the "\" is just indicating that it's a multiline command, you can ignore it.

Comment: I was trying to force it to be a POST request.  I changed it to GET and it is working as expected.  Thank you for your help.  NOTE: If you are the person who demoted my original question please explain.  I'm not sure what was not clear in my request or the work I had completed.

Comment: Yes, I've downvoted it because of IMO poor quality. 1) How did you manage to build OAuth2 flow without encountering examples that mention curl and headers. They're sprinkled across whole SF REST documentation (and apparently also in box.com docs). 2) If you've tried something before posting - why didn't you include any code & sample error messages? This means greater value of the question for future visitors. 3) It's unclear whether your code is written in Apex or in say Objective-C 4) It feels as if you asked for explanation of curl cmd line params. lmgtfy_com etc is banned but tempting